# SQL triggers - conditionals and math operations

Tags: sql

I have some database, lets say like that:

```
|a |b   |c         |d         |e  |
----------------------------------
|0 |12  |NA        |          |   |
|NA|NA  |30        | 42       |   |
|NA|NA  |NA        |          |53 |
```

I'd like to do few things:

1. for first row -  set value to column `D` to be `sin(b)`
2. for second row - if the value is `NA` for column `B`, copy the previous known value (i.e `(a,b)=(0,12)`)
3. on third row - if the value is `NA` for column `B` , copy the previous known value (i.e `(a,b)=(0,12)`) and set value to column `D` to be `sin(b)`.

Those three examples of activities I have to execute on my databases for each row.

If triggers are not the right solution for this, I'd like to have recommendation how to solve it.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the "first row" unless a column specifies that ordering.

Comment: Rows in SQL (and relational DBs in general) are not identified by their order but by their primary key values.  You do not appear to have any keys, primary or otherwise here.

Comment: You can use their entire content as effective keys, if so then you need to describe what you want to implement in terms of rules driven by the rows-content.  For instance you could say: "*If a row has X in column A and Y in column B then put Z in column C*"